# Can Response.Redirect and OnBeforeUnload play nice together?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax, dom-events, asp.net-ajax

Does anyone know how to detect in a `OnBeforeUnload` event that the server side code sent a `Response.Redirect`? I want to prompt a user to keep them from moving away from a page before it's time, but when the server redirects I it shouldn't prompt the user.

I'm working with legacy code that extensively uses `Response.Redirect` and I'm not interested in changing the way the redirect occurs. Please don't suggest I use X redirect method.

<strike>It **should** be possible to do this based on the response code in the XMLHttpRequest object as a response redirect should send back a 302.</strike>

**Edit:** The Response.Redirect sends back a 200, with a redirect code in the body which then does a `window.location.href = new page` in the ASP.Net code. Is there any way to get to the server response to determine that this has happened?

Comment: Response.Redirect sends back a 200 (meaning the page) when you're in an UpdatePanel. I suppose you could intercept the response and change it via an HTTP Module.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I worked out a solution to it.

When the PageRequestManager is processing the response from the server, it will set the _processingRequest flag. In order to allow response.redirect to pass through, I changed my javascript to check for that. The event now looks like this:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function() {
  var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();
  if (!prm._processingRequest){ 
    return "Are you sure you want to leave?";
  }
};
```

Comment: Cool, I also used _xmlHttpRequest.responseText that is contained in the prm to know the destination of the redirect.

Answer (score 0):

For non-ajax pages, you're out of luck since the page is never sent to the browser, just the 302 header. So there's no opportunity for javascript processing of OnBeforeUnload.

With ASP.NET AJAX a Response.Redirect really isn't doing a 302. It's sending back a message via the XMLHttpRequest and ASP.NET AJAX is simulating a 302. In theory you could intercept this and perform your own processing...

Comment: Any idea how to intercept it or get to the actual response?

Comment: @Nathaniel There may be a way to do it in javascript. or you might create an HTTPModule, intercept the page and look for the window.location.href code and rewrite the javascript... Maybe replace it will a function call to do the equivalent of OnBeforeUnload

Comment: @Nathaniel: reading your post further... could you just write some javascript to remove OnBeforeUnload event listener before the redirect occurs?

Comment: @ Keltex That's exactly what I am trying to do. I only want the OnBeforeUnload to be attached while the sever processing is occurring. Unfortunately the PageRequestManager's endRequest callback doesn't fire on a redirect.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, `Response.Redirect` has an overload that lets you decide whether or not to terminate the request (raise a `ThreadAbortException`). If you let the `Response` finish (pass false as the second parameter); `OnBeforeUnload` will also run.

However, simply running `OnBeforeUnload` will not help you in this case, since your client side code (the prompt) will run before a new page can be sent to the browser (and, if you redirect, it will also only be the 302 header and not the real page).

I would use AJAX to query the server, and if it reports the operation to be completed, allow the redirect in the Javascript code.

Comment: Perhaps I wasn't clear in the original post - I'm looking for a way to avoid the OnBeforeUnload prompt if the server is redirecting. Also, after further investigation, ASP.net AJAX isn't sending a 302, but rather is doing its own window.location.href = ... I need a way to detect this.